# Mysql queries don't seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that shows images whos paths are stored in mysql. The form has 'hide' and 'show' submit buttons for each image. Pressing the hide button should set the value of the 'status' field to 2 (hidden). But it does nothing, my queries don't seem to execute.

Here is the form

```
<form  class="removeform"action='headerimageadd.php'  method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'    
name='image_remove_form' > 
     <?php
     include '../inc/connect.php';
     $q = "SELECT * FROM headerrotatorimage WHERE rotator = 1";
     $result = $link->query($q);
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<input type='submit' name='hide[{$row['id']}]' value='Hide'>",
             "<input type='submit' name='show[{$row['id']}]' value='Show'>",
             "<br />",
             "<img src='{$row['filename']}' alt='{$row['name']}' />",
             "<br />";                         
      }
      ?>
      </form>
```

And here is the php that is executed when the hide button is pressed

```
<?php
    include '../inc/connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['hide'])){
       $chk = (array) $_POST['hide'];
       $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
       echo $p;
       $t = "SELECT * FROM headerrotatorimage WHERE id IN ($p)";
       echo $t;
       $s = "UPDATE headerrotatorimage SET status = 2 WHERE id IN ($p)";
       echo $s;
    }
    ?>
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: i dont see you executing your select update queries.., i see you echoing them out but not using them.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually issuing a query in your code:

```
<?php
include '../inc/connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['hide'])){
   $chk = (array) $_POST['hide'];
   $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
   echo $p;
   $t = "SELECT * FROM headerrotatorimage WHERE id IN ($p)";
   echo $t;

   // Execute query and process result set for $t

   $s = "UPDATE headerrotatorimage SET status = 2 WHERE id IN ($p)";
   echo $s;

   // Execute query and process result set for $s
}
?>
```